# Getting error while executing run-android with react-native

Tags: react-native

my english isn't that good. I am from Turkey and sorry if my question isn't clear to you.

When I run `run-android` with React Native, I get the following error but when I run `run-ios` I don't get any issue. I am using a Mac computer.

Thank you for your help.

---

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 1063 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 4 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started.html#android-development-environment. Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
Error: spawn EPERM
    at ChildProcess.spawn (internal/child_process.js:407:11)
    at Object.spawn (child_process.js:548:9)
    at module.exports (/Users/meric/Desktop/Phonder/node_modules/execa/index.js:205:26)
    at runOnAllDevices (/Users/meric/Desktop/Phonder/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/runOnAllDevices.js:94:32)
    at buildAndRun (/Users/meric/Desktop/Phonder/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:182:41)
    at /Users/meric/Desktop/Phonder/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/build/commands/runAndroid/index.js:146:12
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/meric/Desktop/Phonder/node_modules/react-native/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:186:9)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1k9qZ.jpg)

Comment: Did you make sure you have the Android development environment set up by following the link in the error message?

Comment: I wanted to add a screenshot.Yes Ken White android development environment was established.

 [link](https://i.hizliresim.com/IszbNl.png)

Comment: You add an image by using the image toolbar button. Images must be on the SO imgur account, so that they stay with the question. You've also not answered the question I asked. Please [edit] your post to properly add the image and explain what steps you've taken to make sure the Android environment is installed.

Comment: Yes @KenWhite White android development environment was established

Answer (score 0):

I think you should uninstall the app on any emulator or devices, after that please re-run app.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you mean

Comment: You have installed the app before, so this may cause an error for this, you should uninstall the application on the Android virtual machine and then run the React-native run-android command again.

Answer (score 0):

It might be caused by having package.lock.json and yarn.lock at the same time